# angular material date picker wrongly rendered

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I use angular material date picker component, with this piece of code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Date of meeting *</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" formControlName="entityDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But it is wrongly rendered (see following print screen)

[image]

It used to work but not any more. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late answer. In fact, it was my fault : I used the following css that broke the dqte picker template

```
td {
  padding-top: 3px !important;
  padding-bottom: 3px !important;
}
```

When I removed it everything was OK